# Libgdx animation doesn't play or loop

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

I made a game in which a turtle had to collect StarFish but when I added walking animation it doesn't work. What happens is it only shows up the first frame and the whole animation doesn't play and I get no errors.

And I'm using diffrent images to load animation

Here is my animation method-

```
// used to load animation from multiple files
public Animation loadAnimationFromFiles(String[] fileNames, float frameDuration, boolean loop)
{
    int fileCount = fileNames.length;
    Array<TextureRegion> textureArray = new Array<TextureRegion>();
    for (int n = 0; n < fileCount; n++)
    { 
        String fileName = fileNames[n];
        Texture texture = new Texture( Gdx.files.internal(fileName) );
        texture.setFilter( TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear );
        textureArray.add( new TextureRegion( texture ) );
        
    }
    
    Animation anim = new Animation(frameDuration, textureArray);
    if (loop) {
    //setAnimation(anim);
        System.out.println("animation run");
        anim.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
    }
    else {
        anim.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL);
    }
    if (animation == null) {
        System.out.println("animation null");
        setAnimation(anim);
    }
    return anim;
}
```

And here is my turtle class where I used animation-

```
public class Turtle extends BaseActor
{
public Turtle(float x, float y, Stage s)
{
    super(x, y, s);
    
    String[] fileNames = {
        "turtle2.png",
        "turtle.png",
    };

    loadAnimationFromFiles(fileNames, 0.1f, true);
    
}

public void act(float dt)
{   
    super.act(dt);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
        this.moveBy(-5,0);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
        this.moveBy(5,0);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
        this.moveBy(0,5);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN))
        this.moveBy(0,-5);
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You just created the animation, but never used it. To make use of the animation you need to get the textures from it, by measuring the delta time, that passed.

Your turtle class should look more like this:

```
public class Turtle extends BaseActor
{

   private Animation<TextureRegion> animation;//store the animation in a field to use it
   private float time;//use a timer for the animation to be played

   public Turtle(float x, float y, Stage s)
   {
       super(x, y, s);
    
       String[] fileNames = {
           "turtle2.png",
           "turtle.png",
       };

       //store the animation to the field instead of just creating it
       animation = loadAnimationFromFiles(fileNames, 0.1f, true);
       //set the animations timer
       time = 0;
    }

    public void act(float dt)
    {   
        //increase the time since the animation was started by the delta time
        time += dt;
        //tell the animation how much time passed, so it can give you the current animation texture
        TextureRegion texture = animation.getKeyFrame(time);
        
        //TODO draw texture

        //I assume the super.act call also draws a texture; that should be deleted to not draw over the already created texture
        super.act(dt);
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
            this.moveBy(-5,0);
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
            this.moveBy(5,0);
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
            this.moveBy(0,5);
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN))
            this.moveBy(0,-5);
    
    }
}
```